# How does Npgsql handle failed transactions?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, sqltransaction

In an ASP.NET application (C#) we are using Postgres as backend and Npgsql as data provider. A couple of days ago we had a serious problem with loss of data. I investigated in code and found code like this:

```
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    //some crud operation here  
    transaction.Commit()
```

Someone insisted that Npgsql would handle exception by its own and would automatically rollback the transaction in case something went wrong during the transactions.

In my opinion this is quite optimistic, and the code should be wrapped in a try and catch block and call a transaction rollback explicitly:

```
 var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
 try
    {
        //some crud operation here        
        transaction.Commit
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
```

Is that wrong?

Moreover, will a transaction rollback always work? I read somewhere that it will only work if a Postgres exception is raised, say in case of malformed sql, but it will not work in case of other kind of exceptions. Can someone clarify this point too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL will automatically abort, but not rollback, the transaction in case of an error.

The transaction is only done if you

1. disconnect
2. end the transaction with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` (it will rollback in *both* cases)

All statements sent on the connection between the error and the end of the transaction will be ignored.

So yes, you should use a `try` / `catch` block and rollback.

A `ROLLBACK` will always undo the current transaction completely, no matter if there was an error or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But what happens if a .NET IO Exception is thrown during the transaction. Will  the using clause rollback the transaction anyhow or will I need to call an explicit rollback()?

Comment: If the error comes from the database, the transaction is *aborted* but not yet rolled back. If the exception cones from .NET, the transaction is still active (unless the provider aborted it). In both cases, you need an explicit rollback to end the transaction.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "ABORT rolls back the current transaction and causes all the updates made by the transaction to be discarded. This command is identical in behavior to the standard SQL command ROLLBACK, and is present only for historical reasons."

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-abort.html

Comment: @ArturBeljajev I think nobody was talking about the SQL statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I was a bit confused by this: "PostgreSQL will automatically abort, but not rollback". Maybe it is me who got it wrong...

Comment: @ArturBeljajev I see. Maybe I didn't describe it correctly. If you have an error inside a transaction, you go to state `idle in transaction (aborted)`, and you need to run `ROLLBACK` to get it out of that state.

Answer (score 11):

another way could be:

```
using( var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
{
    .. do som database stuff ..

    tx.Commit();
}
```

Dispose on a non committed transaction leads to a rollback. And resources are freed!

Comment: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlTransaction.cs#L366-L389

Should be marked as accepted answer.